# How can I download and set up woff2 font file in offine web page

Tags: css, offline, google-webfonts, woff2

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,600,800,400[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRxN7.jpg)

Where can I get woff2 font file for open sans. Actually Iam finding many formats(cyrillic, greek, vietnamese, latin-ext). Which one I should use for only English

Comment: That would be `latin`. You can download it on Github a little easier: https://github.com/FontFaceKit/open-sans/tree/gh-pages/fonts

Comment: @FabianSchultz - Thank you so much